# Upgrading from Ractive.js v0.5.8 to v0.7.1 and making a call to file Ractive.js.map

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am upgrading an application from Ractive JS v0.5.8 to v0.7.1 and in the browser console, I am getting a 403 (Forbidden) request calling:

```
http://[mydomain.com]/www/RACTIVE/ractive/.gobble-build/02-babel/1/Ractive.js.map
```

What is causing this request, and how do I remedy it?

Comment: Solution (thanks @Rich): I downloaded your sourcemap file from the link you provided below, and in Development mode, it downloads the file. Once minified by grails for QA and Production, those comments are stripped out, so no issue there either. Upgrade went smoothly after that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd - the final line of [ractive.js](http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js) (and the other files) is this:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=ractive.js.map
```

In other words, an instruction for the browser to fetch [the sourcemap](http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js.map) if the console is open, and use that for debugging.

The request you're seeing is for a file that was generated during the build process. We'll remove those intermediate sourcemap comments in the next release (the bundling tool, [esperanto](http://esperantojs.org/), has an [open issue](https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto/issues/120) for this), but in the meantime it looks like that final comment is being stripped out of the file you're using somehow?

Three things that should fix it:

- ensure that the comment shown above is present in your copy of ractive, and place the sourcemap alongside it, or
- use the minified version, which doesn't have those comments, or
- manually remove the comments (find and replace `/\/\/# sourceMappingURL=.+/` with empty lines

If the correct comment *is* present at the end of the file you've using, I'd be curious to know what browser you're in, and how you installed ractive. Thanks

Comment: Answers to your questions for me: I am was (at the time of my question) using the latest Chrome (which is currently Version 42.0.2311.135 m), I am using grails which minifies and uglifies all my JS during QA and Production builds, so I don't use minified versions in development, in case, the during debugging I need to see what is going on under the hood, and I am upgrading so I went to the url offered in the top of the home page (<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>) and, copied the whole file, and pasted it over the version I was currently using.